# sending edittext value from one class to another without intents CHANGE PASSWORD functionality

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext, android-intent

I am implementing CHANGE PASSWORD functionality in my app. I am not allowing the user to enter his username. I will be sending the data to local server. I have defined username edittext in one class. Now for password reset, I want to send only old password,new password and confirm new password entries to the server. I want the username to be fetched without users' knowledge. I learnt we need to use Bundle to pass values but it needs intent. I dont want the user to navigate from his class to another. Is there any other way we can pass edittext value of CLass A to class B without intents?

Comment: It is hard to see why you are not using Intents. These clearly are the best way (unless you use SharedPreferences). Are these classes Activities?

Answer (score 0):

Would [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) help?

From official docs,

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data
>   types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data:
>   booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist
>   across user sessions (even if your application is killed).